# Simple electrical circuit calculation problem

Tags: resistors

I stumbled upon a problem I cannot seem to find the answer for this circuit:

[image: Schematic]

I don't know how the proper term in English is on this, but on the picture the "drsnik" means a "slider", you know the one that splits the resistor basically in two smaller resistors. In this picture the "slider" is on exactly 50%, so it splits the resistors in half.

This is what I had been given: U = 30 V, R = 49 Ω. I need to figure out what the voltmeter would display. All of the resistors are equal and 1,2,3,4,5 represent potentials.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage is:

\$U_0 = U \cdot {{R \cdot n} \over {5 \cdot R}} = U \cdot {n \over 5}\$, where \$n = \$ the point where voltmeter is connected.

So in your case:

\$U_0 = 30 \cdot {{n} \over {5}} = 6 \cdot n \space Volts \$

If you split R between 1 and 2 in half you get:

\$U_0 = 30 \cdot {{1.5} \over {5}} =  {45 \over 5} = 9 V\$

Comment: Wait, but its connected between points 1 and 2 so why would it be two?

Comment: The answer is wrong, and I still dont know how "slider" is properly called in electronics

Comment: @user41740 do you see it connected between points 1 and 2? The circuit suggests that the voltmeter may connect in any of that points.

Comment: as I said its a slider, that splits R between point 1 and point 2 in half (50% "slider" or whatever) so basically half of R is above voltmeter and half is below that point. How do I calculate what voltmeter would display?

Comment: Nicely explained. It's a stupidly looking schematic, took myself a minute to figure it out.

Comment: @Dzarda the problem is that the OP didn't understand that the voltmeter is not connected over R 1-2 at its half...

Comment: Well where is it connected then? Its supozed to split it into two resistors, so Ive been told. Anyone explain me what is going on in this schematics please?

Comment: There are 5 "test points" in the schematic. You connect the voltmeter probe to each and measure the voltage.

Comment: What you dont understand is i got this schematics, and im supozed to figure out what the meter will show in This exact position, and slider is conected to point no.2

Comment: @user41740 in what language is "drsnik"? Because in this context it may mean "voltage probe".

Comment: @user41740 then in point nr 2 you got 12 V. The schematic does no reflect that voltmeter is connected to point 2.

Comment: Im sorry, but i did not make the schematics, thanks for your time. And the "drsnik" is called "Voltage Divider"

Comment: It is pretty simple and doesn't need any (written) math. Ignore the value of the resistors. There are 5 equal resistors across 30 volts. The potential drops by 6 volts across each R (adds to 0 around the loop). So 1 and 2 are 6V and 12V. If there is a slider/wiper/divider dividing the R (not sure about that) then it has to be 6 + 3 = 9V.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put my comment as a second answer - what I would do at the blackboard:

You don't need any (written) math. Ignore the value of the resistors. There are 5 equal resistors across 30 volts. The potential must drop by 6 volts across each R (adds to 0 around the loop). So 1 and 2 are 6V and 12V. If there is a slider/wiper/divider dividing the R (not sure about that) then it has to be 6 + 3 = 9V.

Comment: Because you put your time into answering that, ill put mine aswell. Im sorry I misled you with the picture. Its supozed to be universal picture for more different cases of circuits. Beside my picture it said that voltmeter is connected to point 2, wich made my result 12V.